# Use reporting service configuration to configure the database source name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, upgrade, ssms

So im upgrading to R2. When i get to the Reporting Services Authentication step i get the error:

> There are validation errors on this page. Click ok to close this
> dialog box. Review errors at the bottom of the setup page, then
> provide valid parameters or Click Help for more information.
>
> Use the Reporting Services Configuration tool to configure the
> database source name (DSN) and connect to the database.

What i see is the instance field is blank. I don't know what to do here.

[image]

Comment: And i got a down vote! Why?

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by cancelling the upgrade. Uninstalling the Reporting Service feature. When i reran the upgrade it didnt have this step.